# Is it possible to get file type (and generate a preview) while dragging (before droping)

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to write a drag and drop mechanism that peek into the content of the dragged content **before** it is dropped.

The app is being tested on macOS. But maybe there's some subtleties on other OS.

I've been trying with both approaches `TransferHandler` and `DropTarget`/`DropTargetHandler`.

However in both case I cannot access the dragged content, the `transferable.getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)` returns `null`.

- In `TransferHandler::canImport`, the code check if the flavor is `flavorJavaFileListType`, then it tries to get the data, yet it's `null`.
- In `DropTargetAdapter::dragOver` (or `dragEnter`), the code check if the flavor is `flavorJavaFileListType`, then it tries to get the data, yet it's `null`.

So I'm wondering if this is a constraint of  Swing, of the OS, or simply me not using this properly.

---

Notes:

1. The `TransferHandler::canImport` or `DropTargetAdapter::drop`), function properly.
2. For a unknown reason (at this time) in `TransferHandler::canImport`, I need to `try { trasnferable.getTransferData(...) }  catch (InvalidDnDOperationException ignore)` otherwise when releasing the button (i.e. dropping the content) the call raises this exception `InvalidDnDOperationException: No drop current`.

Comment: Tried on Windows. `transferable.getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)` never retruned `null`, so I could access the file list during the drag. The exception on the drop is reproducible and comprehensible: the `DropTargetDropEvent` only allows access to the transferable after `acceptDrop` has been called but Swing only calls this method after `canImport` returned `true`. This restriction may seem weird as you can access the transferable during the drag, but the possibility to access it during the drag is a newer addition (Java 5). Before that, the restriction may have looked reasonable

Comment: Ah ok, thank you very much for the explanation on the `InvalidDnDOperationException` as I didn't looked into it yet. Also thank you for testing on Windows. That somehow validates my understanding that DnD behavior is different between OSes.

Comment: @Holger By the way I also tried on Linux (Fedora 33) and I was also able to get the content of the files. So it's definitely a limitation of the macOs OS or JDK's macOs implementation.